# Adding a character to a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, text-files

I'm not new to C# and I work with strings all the time but I just can't understand why in this case I can't add a simple character to a simple string!
I'm trying to read a text file into C# so that I can later insert it into a SQL server table.
Anyway, I'm stuck on adding a single quote character to a string. My code is as follows:

```
string text;

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(@"The_Directory\myTextFile.txt", Encoding.UTF8))
{
    text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}

string[] lines = text.Split(new Char[] { '\n' });
string rearrange;

foreach (string line in lines)
{
     rearrange = "*" + line + "'";
     Console.WriteLine(rearrange);  
}
```

What I get as a result doesn't contain the character that I wish to add to the end of the string and only contains the character that I wanted to add to the end, at the beginning.

The output is like this:

```
'The first line
'The second line
```

I can't understand why it doesn't perform the simple string addition. I tried to filter out any possible additional \n character in the lines but it didn't help.

Comment: You split by "\n" instead of the standard Wndows "\r\n" Environment.NewLine but perhaps for a good reason. Can you add a file sample, please?

Comment: Can you provide the contents of  `myTextFile.txt`?

Comment: Your code is rather confusing. There's a `text`string you never initialize, there's a StreamReader you never use... Are you sure you posted your whole code here ?

Comment: Why don't use `string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);` if the file encoding new line is the same as the current platform ?

Comment: Your problem is not in the adding of a character to a string, that part works fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lZMWrz. So your problem lies elsewhere (hard to say without knowing the contents of the file)

Comment: Use the debugger. What is the value of `line` within the loop? You can double check for invalid characters by checking `line.Length` as well.

Comment: I tried with your code with some dummy data. It's works fine, so issur is somewhere else

Comment: I suspect the file content .

Comment: @OlivierRogier Thank you! This solved my problem
```string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);```

Comment: Thanks everyone. The solution of Olivier solved it. I didn't try the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this:

```
using System.IO;

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("The_Directory\myTextFile.txt", Encoding.UTF8);

string rearrange;

foreach (string line in lines)
{
  rearrange = "*" + line + "'";
  Console.WriteLine(rearrange);  
}
```

On Windows, new line is `Environment.Newline = "\r\n"`.

Splitting only on `'\n'` causes that the remaining `'\r'` implies a go to the start of the current line and the `*` is replaced by a `'` when outputed to the console, hence the result.

Because the `\n` historically in DOS causes the cursor only to go to down in the column, if I remember correctly, but I'm not sure, so the need of the `\r` too.

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_Return_Line_Feed

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out by @Olivier, you are splitting on `\n` rather than `\r\n`. That may mean there is still a `\r` character ([carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)) at the end of every line you read. The resulting output is then:

```
*The first line\r'
*The second line\r'
```

which, on a typical terminal emulator, is displayed as:

```
'The first line
'The second line
```

If you could slow down the terminal output, you'd see the `*` is initially there at the start of the line, before being overwritten by the `'`.

---

One way to get rid of the clutter is to strip off trailing whitespace:

```
rearrange = "*" + line.TrimEnd() + "'";
```

Note: None of this will work for files produced on a 'classic' Mac, where newline is a carriage return without linefeed.
I'd recommend following [Olivier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63940126/2485966).

Comment: Indeed `'\r'` go to the start of the current line and replace the `*` by a `'` when outputed to the console.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't try removing \r because the solution of Olivier in reading by other approach worked.

Comment: @Iraj, you can use Enviornment.Newline

Comment: @BijuKalanjoor `System.Environment.NewLine` is not a silver bullet here. A file originating from one platform may be processed on another.

Answer (score 0):

Just try the following small modification in the "Split":

```
    string text;
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(@"The_Directory\myTextFile.txt",Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    string[] lines = text.Replace("\r\n","\n").Split("\n");
    string rearrange;
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        rearrange = "*" + line + "'";
        Console.WriteLine(rearrange);
    }
```

Usually, a normal (Windows) UTF-8 text file has both \r\n on the end of each line. If you split just by \n, then the remaining \r will remain and the result of displaying the \r on the console is that the cursor jumps to the beginning of the current line, before displaying the next character. Thus, it would overwrite the line with the following characters while displaying further text.

Comment: Could you please explain what is the issue in OP? Actually OP works for me.

Comment: This is not the best way to do it. If he is on any other system than Windows this might not work. Remove any `\r` and `\n` or use `System.Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: @PhilippeB. `System.Environment.NewLine` is not a silver bullet here. A file originating from one platform may be processed on another.

Comment: @BijuKalanjoor usually, a normal UTF-8 text file has both \r\n on the end of each line. If you split just by \n, then the remaining \r will remain and the result of displaying the \r on the console is that the cursor jumps to the beginning of the current line, before displaying the next character. Thus, it would overwrite the line with the following characters while displaying further text.

Answer (score -3):

2 Things. Try string.split with stringsplitoptions.RemoveEmptyEntries.
And for the StringBuilding use a StringBuilder instead of concatenating it.

Comment: Be more explicit, why should he use `StringBuilder` in this particular case ? What are the particularity of `string` type ?

Comment: because it is more performant. for every iteration you create 3 strings. with stringbuilder you create only 1 string

Comment: I'm not asking you. I know why, I'm asking that you be more explicit in your answer. SO is a community to help people, giving the answer without any context nor explaination won't do any good to the OP. If you explain him about immutability it will be a huge help for him.

Comment: This is not an answer of OP. You can post these type of information as a comment

Comment: And as @BijuKalanjoor said this doesn't solve OP's problem.

Comment: In  addition to this having nothing to do with the question, it's not even right.  It would perform worse given that the concatenation is only ever done between a fixed number of strings of a small size.  The `+` operator is optimal in that situation.

Comment: Just a side note.. Using a StringBuilder is only more performant when you are dealing with thousands of string builds vs 1 Builder. In this case tacking 3 Strings together... I doubt you would be able to measure the performance difference if any.